# what does "I will step into the ring for you" mean?

Tags: lyrics

The sentence comes from a song.

Leonard Cohen  I am your man
....
If you want a boxer
I will step into the ring for you
......

What does "step into the ring for you"? Someone can explain it for me. Thanks

Comment: General Reference. He means he'll step into the *boxing ring* and fight (as a [champion](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Champion), sense #3) on behalf of the girl he's singing to.

Answer (score 4):

It is a metaphor.

As FumbleFingers has all but said, it means 'I will fight for you' which can be interpreted in two ways:

- I will fight to have you
- I will fight your battles for you

The 'ring' is a boxing ring, where two opponents will fight each other until one wins.